# How to transform Arbitrary Rotation Matrix $A$ to a coordinate system where the $z$ axis lies along the axis of rotation by Similarity Transformation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

In Chapter 4 of the book Classical Mechanics by **Goldstein**, it was written that

> ***"By means of some similarity transformation, it is always possible to transform the matrix A to a system of coordinates where the $z$ axis lies along the axis of rotation"***.

I don't understand how this is done. Can anyone please explain this to me with appropriate physical example with mathematical calculation.

[image: Similarity Transformation]

Answer (score 1):

Let $\hat{n}$ be the axis of rotation and $A(\theta,\hat{n})$ the rotation matrix representing a rotation of angle $\theta$ around it.

1. There exists a rotation matrix $R$ that maps $\hat{n}$ to $\hat{z}$, that is
   $$R\hat{n}=\hat{z}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
   Remember that both $\hat{n}$ and $\hat{z}$ are *unit* vectors. All we're doing here is to consider an orthonormal basis containing $\hat{n}$ and changing to a basis containing $\hat{z}$. Rotations are (proper) isometries, i.e. orthonormal bases are mapped to orthormal bases.
2. Since the matrix $A(\theta,\hat{n})$ is a rotation around $\hat{n}$, the latter is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, which is the trivial statement that the rotation around a vector leaves such vector unchanged. This means
   $$A(\theta,\hat{n})\hat{n}=\hat{n}\tag{2}\label{2}.$$
3. Apply $R$ to both sides of equation \eqref{2}
   $$RA(\theta,\hat{n})\hat{n}=R\hat{n}\underbrace{=}_{\eqref{1}}\hat{z}\tag{3}\label{3}.$$
4. Rotations are invertible maps$^1$. Inverting \eqref{1} we find that
   $$\hat{n}=R^{-1}\hat{z}\tag{4}\label{4}.$$
   Using \eqref{4} in \eqref{3} yields
   $$RA(\theta,\hat{n})R^{-1}\hat{z}=\hat{z}\tag{5}\label{5}.$$
5. Equation \eqref{5} means that $\hat{z}$ is an eigenvector of $RA(\theta,\hat{n})R^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $1$. If we prove this is a rotation matrix, we're done since the axis of rotation is the unique unit eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. It's indeed easy to see that the transpose of the matrix above is its inverse, i.e. the matrix is orthogonal and it has unit determinant, as thw determinant is invariant under similarity transformations.$^2$
6. Finally, since the angle of rotation is the phase of the complex eigenvalues $e^{\pm i\theta}$ of a rotation matrix and the eigenvalues are invariant under similarity transformations, the matrix we have found is a rotation of an angle $\theta$ around $\hat{z}$, that is
   $$A(\theta,\hat{z})=RA(\theta,\hat{n})R^{-1}.\tag{6}\label{6}$$

---

$^1$ <sub>Consider the rotation of the opposite angle around the same axis. The matrix representing the inverse rotation is the transpose matrix.</sub>

$^2$ <sub>After all, rotation form a group and the product of two rotations is still a rotation.</sub>